# ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-manifest

This is how my MainActivity and RecorderService Java class files looks like. I'm adding the AndroidManifest file too.

**MainAcitivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      btnSendSOS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendSMS();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), RecorderService.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();

                new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecorderService.class));
                }
            }.start();
      });


}
```

**RecorderService.java**

```
public class RecorderService extends Service {
     // Service code here
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".RecorderService" />
</application>
```

I have added the service to the Manifest file. But still I'm getting the error: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {.RecorderService}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: dont use base context just use activity name. this and give full path of service class in manifest, and use startService not startActivity...and then clean ur project then try..

Comment: Ummm, you're trying to start your `Service` using `startActivity(intent);`. You need to use `startService(intent);` - the clue is in the method name.

Comment: @RohitGoswami sorry. my bad.. i didnt see that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RecorderService` is **Service**. is not an `Activity`. And `Start Service` like

```
  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RecorderService.class);
  startService(i);
```

Go to [Official Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for more information regard `Services` in **Android**

Comment: I'd change `getBaseContext()` to `MainActivity.this`. Using the base Context is rarely necessary. Other than that, your answer is obviously correct.